# How to keep electronics warm in cold countries?

Tags: batteries

We speak about -50 celsius degrees. Is there any (cheap, diy) way how to keep batteries warm ?

Electronic hearing with resistors ?

Chemical heating ?

Any hints will be greatly appriciated

Thank you

Comment: What kind of electronics are you talking about? Would I be right in assuming a phone/laptop/tablet/etc? And what are the conditions in which you'll be using it? (i.e. mostly in a heated room with occasional trips out into the cold, or open to the elements all day?)

Comment: Although regardless of the answers to those questions, I very strongly suggest the only real solution is buying ruggedized hardware. -50 is a long, long way from the conditions standard consumer electronics are built for, and your suggestions don't sound like something I'd recommend building yourself unless you have the background knowledge to - at a very minimum - confidently answer this question for yourself.

Comment: we speak about action camera and smartphone. I want to keep recording, vloging on move. Yes I do have skills to build anything electronic related, but lack of real life experiences. For example, I can make heater out of power bank, question is, will it be usefull since powerbank itself will be drained down quite fast even without that device. Thanks

Comment: drones can operate in -35 celsius when they are heated before flight and leaved on place turned on for a while to let them warm inside. Anyhow, that's just experience of some people, not mine. I'm taking drone with me too, will try. Still, smartphone is the question #1

Comment: This question may be helpful to you - https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/how-to-properly-insulate-electronic-devices-in-a-car/23074#23074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets tricky to use electronic equipment already at much higher temperatures than the -50°C you are targetting in your question. Be aware that the problem is not only limited to the batteries, but to many other electronic and mechanical parts. Going down to -50°, you will risk both temporary malfunctioning and perhaps even permanent damage to your equipment.

One problem is of course the battery. Most Li-Ion batteries show a noticeable loss of capacity already when going below 0°C. Some devices designed for outdoor operation in cold climate, e.g. electrical vehicles, do indeed come with self-heating systems, where energy from the battery itself is used to warm the battery. It is however not really feasible to implement a DIY-version of such a system for an existing product. You need deep knowledge about the battery's characteristics to decide under which conditions it is actually profitable to drain energy from the battery to increase the temperature. Consumer grade electronical devices are also rarely designed in such a way that you can practically only warm the battery and not the entire device. A battery for most common devices is also way too small, even under optimal conditions, to contain enough energy to heat up the device for a significant amount of time. Be aware that [charging a li-ion battery below 0°C may easily cause permanent damage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263036/why-charging-li-ion-batteries-in-cold-temperatures-would-harm-them).

But there are also other problems:

- Most electronical components behave depending on the temperature, the resistance of a regular resistor and the capacitance of most kinds of capacitors correlate with temperature. At extreme temperatures, the real values and characteristics of the components may differ so much from the intended values, that a circuit simply does not work anymore. Capacitors with a liquid dielectric material may be permanently damaged if the dielectric freezes and expands.
- LCD displays start lagging at moderate temperatures below 0°C. The crystals forming the image are suspended in a liquid and at lower temperatures, the liquid becomes viscous and prevents the crystals from moving freely. I've had LCD displays permanently damaged after using (or trying to use them) around -30°C for shorter periods of time. AMOLED displays are not that susceptible to cold temperatures.
- Mechanical parts may also malfunction or fail in the cold. Cameras may contain moving parts and the lubrication may thicken or even turn solid in the cold. Plastic parts can get brittle and combined with lack of lubrication do funny things.

Depending on how the device is built and how it is operated, it may be feasible to accomodate it in an insulated casing with room for hand warmers. You will likely have to build this casing yourself. I assume that fuel and charcoal powered hand warmers produce water vapour, but crystallisation warmers should be safe.

You may be able to store the devices inside at regular temperatures and take them out for shorter periods, but that may as Max already wrote, also cause problems with condensation. Not only inside the devices, but a camera lens is of course very prone to condensation, but more when you bring a cold device into a warm room and not when bringing a warm camera outside into the cold.

Answer (score 3):

For small batteries (cameras, phones...) , keep them in pockets inside your coat, close to your body.

For bigger batteries, you could use an ice-chest with some hand warmer pads to keep the batteries warm.

There are some suggestions [here](http://www.droneriot.com/flying-a-drone-in-cold-weather/).

Comment: Keeping a typical camera close to your body can be problematic.  It gets cold and dry when you take it out to use it, but then you put it back into a warm and moist environment.  This is the perfect recipe for causing condensation inside the camera and can cause all sorts of problems.  The best practice is to bag the camera up before bringing it into somewhere warm.  However the OP has mentioned an action cam for which I would expect this to be less of an issue.

Comment: That's why I wrote about batteries.

Comment: For some reason I read that as "small batteries, cameras and phones".  Blame it on a caffeine deficient diet :D

Answer (score 2):

You can get lens heaters (battery powered). They're used by amateur astronomers and photographers.

I don't know about -50°C though, that's quite extreme.

There are also chemical hand warmers, both one-shot type and re-usable phase-change types. Maybe consider a small urethane insulated cooler with those inside. I suspect you're going to have more of a problem operating the electronics, especially if there is any wind. Lobster gloves and such like don't give much dexterity and bare flesh freezes very quickly even at a relatively balmy -35°C if the wind is blowing.